# In Angular v16 unsubscribe from an Obserable using takeUntillDestroy or toSignal what should I do

Tags: angular, rxjs, signals, unsubscribe

In my Angular application I have too many api links to talk with backend. Most of my services are like that. Inside a service:

```
getData():Obserable<any>{
return this.http.get('myapli/get/data/any')
}
```

and from my component I simply call it :

```
this.mysrvice.getData().subscribe({next:res=>log('res')})
```

when unsubscribing from it I used to have a component that I implement and use it to unsubscribe, however in my new application I want to use eaither `toSignal()` or  `takeUntillDestroy`,
what do you think is better? Should I keep calling takeuntilldestory in every function? or how to use toSignal?

I tried to
`destoryRef = inject(DestroyRef)`
and in my function
`this.myservice.getData().pipe(takeUntillDestroy()).subscribe`
and it seemed to work, but still not sure if it was best approach.

Answer (score 0):

`toSignal` relies on the same mecanism as `toUntilDestroyed` : `DestroyRef`, so basically it's the same.

So for the sake of readability, `toSignal` would be recommended.

Comment: Thnak you I will try implementing it,

Answer (score 0):

In a component, you should prefer toSignal(). It automatically unsubscribes and updates the Dom tree when the service emits a new value.
You can use it like this:

```
const data = toSignal(this.myService.getData())
```

In your template, you can then access your signal as a function

```
{{ data() }}
```

Comment: A bit confused here.
In each component i have like 15 function that talk to back end same logic as above call it from a service, how do I implement this logic of unsubscription here i also do some logic after subscription below 
  `res=>{log('res'); this.someLogic..}`